# Get the last 10 articles via JSON from newspaper API works but how to load the next 10?

Tags: ios, json, offset

Working on an iPhone App fetches newspaper articles from the web.

For performance purposes only the last 10 articles will be send per `request`.

All works as expected but how do I get the next 10 articles when user scrolls down and wants to read more?

- **Working**: First `request` gives me articles: 1 - 10
- **NOT Working**: `Request` send again should give me articles: 11 - 20 (by setting an `offset`)

(When I read the API documentation I am supposed to set an `offset` to get the next articles but it doesn't work, I always get the same first 10 articles based on my search query.)

Following `request` searches for the last 10 articles with the `keyword` **frankfurt** in it
and sets an `offset` of 10 which should send me the next 10 articles when I send the `request` again.

http://api.zeit.de/content?q=frankfurt&limit=10&offset=10&api_key=MY_API_KEY

From the API documentation:

> *Search results are limited to 10 matches by default. You can increase this value with the limit parameter. To iterate over the resultset, repeat your request with the offset parameter set to multiples of the limit.*

UPDATE:

```
- (IBAction)runBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSError *error;
    
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.zeit.de/content?q=frankfurt&fields=teaser_title%20AND%20release_date&limit=5&offset=5&sort=release_date%20desc&api_key=123456789"]];
    
    NSDictionary *dictFromData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    
    NSArray *array = dictFromData[@"matches"];
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
}
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

```
2013-01-10 17:21:39.261 ZEITreisen[94644:c07] (
        {
        "release_date" = "2013-01-03T06:00:00Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Im Stich gelassen";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-28T13:18:58Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Serbiens Nachwuchs baut den Weg nach Europa";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-27T10:18:07Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Das Fu\U00dfballgott bestrafte Hoffenheim";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-27T06:00:00Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Sind Fitschen und Jain die Richtigen f\U00fcr 2013?";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-27T06:00:00Z";
        "teaser_title" = Sparen;
    }
)
2013-01-10 17:21:43.447 ZEITreisen[94644:c07] (
        {
        "release_date" = "2013-01-03T06:00:00Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Im Stich gelassen";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-28T13:18:58Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Serbiens Nachwuchs baut den Weg nach Europa";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-27T10:18:07Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Das Fu\U00dfballgott bestrafte Hoffenheim";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-27T06:00:00Z";
        "teaser_title" = "Sind Fitschen und Jain die Richtigen f\U00fcr 2013?";
    },
        {
        "release_date" = "2012-12-27T06:00:00Z";
        "teaser_title" = Sparen;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might running into an instance where the API incorrectly prioritizes some parameters over others to the point of ignoring your offset. Try removing your limit since you're using the default, or try using different numbers between limit and offset. There may be some poor comparisons being made that are preventing your offset from being accepted. Without API docs, it is hard to say though what could be going wrong. I would second @Geraud.ch's suggestion though if modifying your query string doesn't work: contact the API provider.

**Edit** just realized you posted the actual URL. I'm searching for docs now.

Comment: Saw this post after I have answered my question. You are right. I have to use different numbers for the offset to get this working. (To be specific, `limit=10 offset=10` for the first call, second call: `limit=10 offset=20` and so on...)

Comment: It was a lucky guess. Really you should accept your own answer. I don't need the internet points that badly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. `Offset` must increase EVERY time you re-call it then it works.

Example:

**First call:** (NO OFFSET)

```
http://api.zeit.de/content?q=frankfurt&fields=teaser_title%20AND%20release_date&limit=5&sort=release_date%20desc&api_key=123456789
```

**Next time you call the API just add 5 to the offset and it works.**

```
http://api.zeit.de/content?q=frankfurt&fields=teaser_title%20AND%20release_date&limit=5&offset=5&sort=release_date%20desc&api_key=123456789
```

Note: Second request leaves the first 5 search results out and delivers the next 5.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, it's hard to say. But what you have in mind seems good.

You might have an error in your request (have you logged them to see if the parameter is well set, without any typo? what about the response?) or the API might have an error. In that case, you should contact the provider directly.

Comment: Hi Geraud, Just updated my original post with `code` and `console output`. Nevertheless I set an `offset` I always get the same `JSON` response.